# If every the sum of the degrees of every pair of nonadjacent vertices exceeds $\left|V(G)\right|+k$, then $\kappa(G)=k+2$.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $ k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Suppose that for every pair of nonadjacent verticles $x,y$ in a graph $G$, $$\deg_G(x) + \deg_G(y) \ge n+k.$$  Prove that $ \kappa \ge k+2$.

Here $n$ denotes the order of $G$ and $\kappa$ denotes the smallest number of vertices to which we can erase so that the graph remains connected.

I am grateful for any help. Does this have something to do with the Ore theorem?

Comment: I have edited this question for grammar and diction.  Please review the changes to ensure I have not modified its content.

Comment: Ore's theorem ensures, if your preconditions holds with $k=0$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian. Hamiltonian graphs are 2-connected. So, it proves your theorem in case $k=0$. Maybe, you can somehow go on with induction by removing one vertex.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderGruber

Comment: @AlexanderGruber there was one mistake but I've changed it.

Comment: @Tomas induction of the vertex?
I'm not sure how to do it properly.
so suppose that this is true: $ deg_G(x) + deg_G(y) \ge n-1+k then \kappa = k+2 $ . Let's add one vertex. Then we have got (in the worst way) $ deg_G(x) + deg_G(y) +2 \ge n+k $ This is true becouse of assumption so $ \kappa $ can't be less than k+2 becouse we have more edges. Hmm correct?

Answer (score 1):

I will proof this for all integers $k\geq -1$. Induction on $k$:

- $k=-1$. If $G$ is not connected, then there are at least two components, one of which has at most $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ vertices, then for $x,y$ in this component:
  $$\deg(x)+\deg(y)\leq \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1\leq n-2$$
  a contradiction, so the graph is connected and $\kappa\geq 1 = -1+2$.

For the induction step, we use Menger's theorem, so we want to show that between any pair of nonadjacent vertices there are at least $k+2$ distinct paths.

- $k\geq 0$. Pick any two nonadjacent vertices $x$ and $y$ and suppose 
  $$\deg_G(x)+\deg_G(y)\geq n+k$$
  Define
  $$W(x,y) := \{a\in V(G) \mid ax,ay\in E\} \subset V(G)$$
  This set is not-empty, since otherwise, if $x$ and $y$ shared no common neighbour, any of the $n-2$ other vertices are adjacent to at most one of $x$ and $y$ so $\deg(x)+\deg(y)\leq n-2$, a contradiction.

  If $|W(x,y)|\geq k+2$, then we have found $k+2$ distinct paths. So, assume $|W(x,y)|\leq k+1$.

  Now construct a new graph $G'$ by deleting every vertex of $W(x,y)$. Since each such vertex had at most on edge to $\{x,y\}$, we have
  $$\deg_{G'}(x)+\deg_{G'}(y)\geq \deg_G(x)+\deg_G(y)-|W(x,y)|\geq n+k - |W(x,y)|$$
  Now, $k - |W(x,y)|\geq -1$ and the induction hypothesis applies, so there are at least $k-|W(x,y)|+2$ distinct paths in $G'$. Now each of those paths is a path in $G$ as well and for each $v\in W(x,y)$, then $xvy$ is a path as well and they are all distinct, so there are $k+2$ distinct paths.

Comment: Thanks, I need to think about it.

Comment: Of course! If you have any question or spotted a mistake, ask away.